# Memory allocation for objects in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

so this is my code [ notice that I commented the cstr and destructor]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <array>

class MyIntClass
{
    int _mymember;

  public:  

// MyIntClass(){}
// ~MyIntClass(){}

void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "new: Allocating " << size << " bytes of memory" << std::endl;
    void *p = malloc(size);

    return p;
}
void operator delete(void *p)
{
    std::cout << "delete: Memory is freed again " << std::endl;
    free(p);
}


void *operator new[](size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "new: Allocating " << size << " bytes of memory" << std::endl;
    void *p = malloc(size);

    return p;
}

  void operator delete[](void *p)
    {
        std::cout << "delete: Memory is freed again " << std::endl;
        free(p);
    }
};

void line(){
        std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    line();
    std::cout << "Using new overloading and malloc\nWe will create one object of MyIntClass that is supposed to be 4 bytes" << std::endl;
    MyIntClass *m1 = new MyIntClass();

    line();
    //I want to create an array of the MyIntClass of two objects
    std::cout << "Now we create array of MyIntClass using <array> header" << std::endl;
    std::array<MyIntClass, 2> z = {};

    std::cout << " The elements in the array z = "<< z.size() <<std::endl;

    std::cout << "The memory allocated for  array z = " << sizeof(z) << std::endl;

    line();

    std::cout << "\nNow we create array using new[] overloading and malloc " << std::endl;

    MyIntClass *i = new MyIntClass[2]();
    delete[] i;
}
```

now the result is as follow:

> ---
>
> Using new overloading and malloc
>     We will create one object of MyIntClass that is supposed to be 4 bytes
>
> new: Allocating 4 bytes of
>   memory
>
> ---
>
> Now we create array of MyIntClass using `<array>` header
>   The elements in the array z = 2
>   The memory allocated for  array z = 8
>
> ---
>
> Now we create array using new[] overloading and malloc
>    new: Allocating  8 bytes of memory

To me as inexperienced C++ programmer I think every thing is working as expected

Now If I uncomment the constructor the same result will happen

however when I uncomment the destructor different result will occur

> Now we create array using new[] overloading and malloc
>    new: Allocating  12 bytes of memory

So my question is what is the explanation for this:
creating array of two objects each is 4 bytes will result in 8byte memory allocation for the array in both methods using the `array` library or the overloading the new[] and malloc.

however when we have a destructor for the object the malloc will allocate 12 bytes not 8 bytes for this array of 2 elements.

I saw this  [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749922/why-does-new-allocate-1040-extra-bytes-the-first-time) but it didn't explain my case

following is my compiler version :

> gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3)

Comment: Deleting all these redundant empty lines would make your code *a lot more readable* — all without any change to the actual code!

Comment: What is "memalloc"?

Comment: The behaviour of the program is undefined because you use `delete` on a pointer that wasn't returned by `new` (it was returned by `new[]`).

Comment: Try printing out `sizeof(MyIntClass)` for your various configurations of the class.

Comment: @eerorika If I understand correctly, this is an issue only because `operator delete` was not overloaded by OP? Otherwise it would be fine I think.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No. Using anything other than `delete[]` to free a pointer allocated with `new[]` has undefined behaviour. Regardless of overloaded operators.

Comment: I added the delete overloading .. the same behavior ... when the object has a destructor the malloc will assign the (elements * size of every element) + size of the element

Comment: @eerorika I added `delete[] i`  but the same behavior is persisting

Answer (score 2):

The reason for extra allocated memory is that the compiler needs to know the number of elements in the array in order to be able to call destructors on each element of the array when you call `delete[]`. For trivially destructible types the compiler doesn't need to call destructor, so the extra space for the array size is not needed.

Comment: You said "the compiler needs to know the number of elements in the array in order to be able to call destructors " but the number is already specified here `std::array<MyIntClass, 2> z = {};` and here `MyIntClass *i = new MyIntClass[2]();` ; so why is the space allocated is different although we specified the number of elements on compile time not the runtime? I am still confused, but thank you for your reply

Comment: `std::array` (and C-style array) does not dynamically allocate memory. The size of the array always `N * sizeof(T)`, where N is known at compile time and need not be stored separately. The important part is that N is statically known to the compiler at the point of destroying the array. OTOH, when you call `operator new[]`, the number of elements is a runtime value (even if you specify it as a constant), which cannot be inferred from the returned pointer. That runtime value needs to be stored somewhere so that `operator delete[]` is able to call the destructors.